# How to make substitution using parallel ranges?

Tags: equation-solving, prime-numbers

Example :
$$y=x^2+x+1,$$
where

1st range: $x=$ 1 to 1,000,000;

2nd range: $x=$ 1,000,001 to 2,000,000;

3rd range: $x=$ 2,000,001 to 3,000,000.

Answer (score 1):

For this purpose you can take `Union` of the `Range`,

```
Union[Range[1, 10], Range[11, 20], Range[21, 30]]
```

> {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 
>   20, 21, 22, 23, 24, 25, 26, 27, 28, 29, 30}

```
f = x^2 + x + 1 /. x -> %
```

> {3, 7, 13, 21, 31, 43, 57, 73, 91, 111, 133, 157, 183, 211, 241, 273,
>    307, 343, 381, 421, 463, 507, 553, 601, 651, 703, 757, 813, 871,
>   931}

```
Show[Plot[x^2 + x + 1, {x, 1, 30}, PlotStyle -> {Green}, Frame -> True], 
ListPlot[f, PlotStyle -> {Red}, Frame -> True]]
```

[image]